# laravel validatetor in controller seems not working

Tags: laravel

The validate() function from my sales controller seems not working, I am comparing it to my other controller, it looks like it should work but it is not. it looks like the validate() is being bypassed. here's my controller

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class SalesController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'user_id' => 'required',
            'status_id' => 'required',
            'currency_id' => 'required',
            'company_id' => 'required',
            'invoice_no' => 'nullable',
            'notes' => 'nullable',
            'admin_notes' => 'nullable',
            'due_date' => 'nullable',
            'publish' => 'nullable',
            'product_id' => 'required|min:1',
            'product_code' => 'required|min:1',
            'product_name' => 'required|min:1',
            'quantity' => 'required'
        ]);


         $sales = $request->only(
            'user_id',
            'status_id',
            'currency_id',
            'currency_rate',
            'due_date',
            'company_id',
            'invoice_no',
            'notes',
            'admin_notes',
            'delivery_date',
            'publish'
        );
        $sales['grandtotal'] = (float) str_replace(',', '', $request->grandtotal);
        $sales['grandtotalcost'] = (float) str_replace(',', '', $request->grandtotalcost);
        $sales = Sales::create($sales);

        $input = $request->all();
        for($i=0; $i<= count($input['quantity']); $i++) {
        if(empty($input['quantity'][$i]) || !is_numeric($input['quantity'][$i])) continue;
            $items = [ 
                'sales_id' => $sales->id,
                'product_id' => $input['product_id'][$i],
                'product_code' => $input['product_code'][$i],
                'product_name' => $input['product_name'][$i],
                'price' => $input['price'][$i],
                'cost' => $input['cost'][$i],
                'quantity' => intval($input['quantity'][$i]),
                'total_price' => (float) str_replace(',', '', $input['total_price'][$i]),
                'total_cost' => (float) str_replace(',', '', $input['total_cost'][$i]),
            ];

            Salesitems::create($items);
        }

        // $ponumbers = Ponumbers::create($request->only('purchase_no'));
        $invnum = $request->all();
        $invnumbers = new Invnumbers;
        $invnumbers->sales_num = $invnum['invoice_no'];
        $invnumbers->save();

        if ($request){
            Session::flash('message','Invoice was successfully added');
            Session::flash('m-class','alert-success');
        } else {
            Session::flash('message','Data is not saved');
            Session::flash('m-class','alert-danger');
            return redirect()->route('sales.index');
        }
        return redirect()->route('sales.index');
    }
}
```

My Blade

```
<input class="form-control autocomplete_txt product_name" type='text' data-type="product_name" id='product_name_1' name='product_name[]' for="1" readonly/>
@if ($errors->has('product_name')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('product_name') }}</p> @endif
```

if I submit my form with product name, instead of throwing error from validate,

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By seeing your code, to me it seems your `product_id` should be an array. So the validation should be:

`'product_id' => 'array|required|min:1',`

`'product_id.*' => 'required',`

instead of

`'product_id' => 'required|min:1',`

Comment: Hi @Imran, yes it is an array. I just followed your suggestion but still it has an error.

Comment: What is the error now? Is it same as before or we have solved the validation issue with this and facing another one?

Comment: same error, Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'product_id' cannot be null... currently here's my validate looks like, $this->validate($request, [
    'product_id' => 'array|required|min:1',
]);  ... I exclude the other part

Comment: Can you add `dd($input);`  after this line: `$input = $request->all();` and tell me what you have in `product_id` key?

Comment: here's the result @lmran   "product_id" => array:3 [▼
    0 => null
    1 => null
    2 => null
  ] it is my intension to make the product_id nulled so that I can test if the validate is working

Comment: Ohh, I see. That's the issue. In that case you need to add another validation line. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I think it working because the form is not sending but its not returning the error message

Comment: That's a good  news. Feel free to upvote and approve the answer if it satisfy your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191279/discussion-between-lito-and-imran).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$request->validate([...` instead of `$this->validate($request, [...`. I'm not sure is there `validate` in your controller...

Comment: Try to replace `'product_id' => 'required|min:1',` by `'product_id.*' => 'required',`. This should check each element in your `product_id` array. But I'm not sure it would work. Saw it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#validating-arrays).

Comment: Hi @Petr I think it working because the form is not sending but its not returning the error message